# Java applets contained in packages

Tags: java, html, applet

Can I have an applet live in a package? ie:

```
bfwd.RedemptionOnline.client
```

would be the package, and RedemptionOnlineApplet.class would live inside that package. If you can, how would you create the  tag for it if it lived inside RedemptionOnline.jar?

here is the tag i'm using:

```
<applet code="bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet" width="1" height="1" archive="RedemptionOnline.jar">
    <PARAM NAME="MAYSCRIPT" VALUE="true">
</applet>
```

and here is a log of the error i'm getting:

```
Java Plug-in 10.0.0.147
Using JRE version 1.7.0-b147 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\LordZardeck
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1b1a66b
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar
network: Cache entry found [url: http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
network: Connecting http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar with cookie "PHPSESSID=loub2i9mprilg7ihvjn8g960v1"
network: ResponseCode for http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar : 304
network: Encoding for http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar : null
network: Disconnect connection to http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar
cache: Reading Signers from 5 http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar | C:\Users\LordZardeck\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\4\40bb90c4-62ab3bc6.idx
network: No certificate info for unsigned JAR file: http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar
cache:  Read manifest for http://localhost/redemption/RedemptionOnline.jar: read=82 full=82
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/redemption/, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/redemption/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/redemption/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/redemption/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class with cookie "PHPSESSID=loub2i9mprilg7ihvjn8g960v1"
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost/redemption/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class, version: null]
network: Connecting http://localhost/redemption/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost/redemption/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class with cookie "PHPSESSID=loub2i9mprilg7ihvjn8g960v1"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bfwd.RedemptionOnline.client.RedemptionOnlineApplet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: load: class bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bfwd.RedemptionOnline.client.RedemptionOnlineApplet
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@1b1a66b
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Applet class is packaged inside a JAR file which is downloadable by http://example.com/RedemptionOnline.jar, then you should specify the packaged class' full qualified name in `code` and the (relative) public web URL of the JAR file in `archive` (note: case sensitive!):

```html
<applet code="bfwd.RedemptionOnline.client.RedemptionOnlineApplet" archive="RedemptionOnline.jar">
```

*(I agree with Jon that package names should be lowercased, conform [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367))*

If your Applet class is just a loose `.class` file in public web content which is downloadable by http://example.com/bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class, then you should specify exactly its (relative) public web URL in `code` instead (note: also case sensitive!):

```html
<applet code="bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class">
```

Do you now understand when to use periods and when to use slashes and when to suffix `.class`?

Comment: You need to be more specific about "doesn't work". What happens? What happens not? Do you still get that `ClassNotFoundException`? Then there's simply no `bfwd/RedemptionOnline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class` file in the JAR. Extract the JAR to be sure. Rebuild the JAR if necessary. Or perhaps your browser has an old version of the JAR in the cache, clear browser cache or rename JAR file.

Comment: my error log is posted in my question. it's not finding the applet class i believe

Comment: Download `http://example.com/RedemptionOnline.jar` in your browser and open it with some ZIP tool. Is the class file in there in the expected folder (package) structure?

Comment: i've cleared the cache, rebuilt the jar, and i've looked in the jar. yet it's still not working. i'll upload the file to my server if you want to check for yourself

Comment: wait, is it case sensitive? scratch that. yes it is.

Comment: Definitely. That's among others also why naming conventions exist.

Comment: ok, this is another topic pertaining to the same project. how do I add dependencies? for example, my applet uses a sfs2x-client-core.jar library. how do I include that? just add it to the RedemptionOnline.jar root directory?

Comment: The `archive` attribute accepts commaseparated paths. You can just specify URLs to other JARs in there. You only need to ensure that those JARs are also in public webcontent so that they can be downloaded by the client (webbrowser) :)

Comment: sweet, that worked. To avoid making this comment way to big, and since it's entirely a different error, should i start a new question for my next problem?

Comment: If that's unrelated to the initial question, then definitely you need to ask a new question :)

Comment: alright. thanks alot. I really think i'm understanding this whole applet and archive thing. out of curiosity though, COULD you include all the dependencies in a single jar? like, for example, if you had a stand-alone app?

Comment: Technically, yes. Eclipse for example can do it in a few clicks. Legally, that depends. Read the licenses of those 3rd party JARs if repackaging and redistributing is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, applets can be in packages - although I would advise you to follow conventions and name the package something like

```
com.bfwd.redemptiononline.client
```

When you create the tag, you'd just specify the fully-qualified name:

```
com.bfwd.redemptiononline.client.RedemptionOnlineApplet.class
```

or possibly (documentation varies and it's a long time since I've done any applet work)

```
com.bfwd.redemptiononline.client.RedemptionOnlineApplet
```

or even:

```
com/bfwd/redemptiononline/client/RedemptionOnlineApplet.class
```

Comment: may I ask why com? Also, minus the com, i've tried ALL those. could you give me an actual <applet> tag to try? maybe i'm not formatting my tag right

Comment: @LordZardeck: By convention, Java package names start with DNS names in reverse. And no, I don't have a sample applet tag I can easily show - but you could look at view-source:http://www.tantrix.com/cgi-bin/gs_logon.cgi?pname=guest&language=?pname=guest&language=

Comment: Ok, I even tried with the slash. Maybe you can make sense of this log:

Comment: i couldn't add the log since it was to long. so I edited my original question to contain it

Comment: @LordZardeck: Judging by the ClassNotFoundException, try without the .class on the end. If that still doesn't work, edit your question again to include the tag *and* the log.

Comment: @LordZardeck: Could you also run `jar tvf RedemptionOnline.jar` and paste the results?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3109/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-lordzardeck)